# Unity Editor Scripting: BoxCollider-like scene controls

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I've come across a few scenarios for "Faking" Colliders using `Bounds` - mainly when I only need to keep an object inside a certain area (using `Bounds.Contains`), and don't want it to participate in physics.

I know I could use a Trigger for this, but that would require a dedicated layer, which isn't an option as my game is out of layers.

I created a simple `BoundsHolder` script, which uses local size/center to calculate Bounds. 
I display them in editor using `Gizmos.DrawWireCube`- this works just fine as seen below:

[image: Custom Bounds Holder inspector + scene gizmo]

But I would like to add the drag controls `BoxCollider` has for enlarging my bounds:

[image: Unity BoxCollider Scene gizmo with drag-to-enlarge handles]

I've searched around google + browsed the docs for `Gizmos` and `Handles`- But all of the functions there seem to be about *drawing* cubes, not resizing tools.

**Is there a built in tool to recreate this I'm missing?**

If not- **what would be the best way to go about this?**

---

**Bonus question-** My BoundsHolder uses `UnityEngine.Bounds` which is axis-aligned and doesn't support rotation. Is there an alternative version that supports rotation? (and still provides the `Contains(Vector3)` API?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, handles are there to draw stuff but also interact - so that you can actually grab the handle. 
Afaik you have to implement scaling the box yourself. But a [Handles.ScaleHandle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.ScaleHandle.html) could help. Or create a [Slider to move along one axis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.Slider.html)

For the Box-Collider-Trigger thing, you can look into [Physics.CheckBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckBox.html) (a true/false hitTest for boxes with orientation)

or into 
[Physics.OverlapBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html) (which gives you a list of gameobjects that are inside - this can be used like "contains" if you like)

As you don't want an extra layer you can set the layermask to "everything" and check the object reference or the tag to make sure you have the correct object.

Answer (score 0):

There is rendering mechanism using matrix as pipeline. so if you want to make it move, scale, rotation
Make matrix to do that, If I do same job, then I will started with "transform.localToWorldMatrix"

Matrix4x4 matrix4x4 = transform.localToWorldMatrix;

Matrix A

0 0 0 T

0 0 0 T

0 0 0 T

0 0 0 0

The part of 'matrix A', 'T' tralsate part from that matrix so you can change or add offset to move more from current gameObject.
Then, applie it to draw like

```
public void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Matrix4x4 matrix4x4 = transform.localToWorldMatrix;

    ....
    ....
    do something with "matrix4x4" here


    Gizmos.matrix = matrix4x4; // apply matrix to move/scale/rotate
    Gizmos.DrawCube(..)
}
```